# Generate Server Key programmatically for Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am building a custom console to send Push Notifications to our apps.

In order to send push I have to perform a POST HTTP Request with following params:

HTTP POST https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Headers:

Authorization key=12345678900987654321

Content-Type application/json

And the body as JSON.

The Server Key (Authorization Key) can be generated from Firebase console.

However, I have a requirement to generate this key programmatically each time app Admin sends a notifications.

So the Server Key is not hard coded, not saved in a file in my server.

The server key is only retrieved from Firebase by deleting previous key and generating new key programmatically.

Does FCM Admin or API provide a way to perform Server Key generation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is currently no available API or workaround to generate a Server Key dynamically.

As you seem to be already aware, the usual use case for the Server Key is to be stored in a safe environment and be used accordingly.

> *However, I have a requirement to generate this key programmatically each time app Admin sends a notifications.*

This is a strange requirement. You don't need to generate a different Server Key every time you'll push a message. The server key is usable until you choose to delete it on your console.